# Copying Columns Missing a Step

Tags: excel, vba

The issue is that up to a certain point, each column is copied to the right, and then it suddenly starts going to the left, and ignoring a column.

I didn't write the thing, have as yet been unable to pick it apart to even attempt to solve it properly. I've fiddled with it, but haven't gotten any useful results to go off of.

```vb
For colx = 2 To maxColumns Step 2
ActiveSheet.Columns(colx).Insert
ActiveSheet.Columns(colx - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
Next

maxRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
maxColumns = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count * 2 + 1

For colx = 2 To maxColumns Step 2
For iRow = 1 To maxRows
WorksheetFunction.CountA (Columns(1))
'If there is a comment, paste the comment text into column D and delete the original comment.
ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, colx).Value = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, colx - 1).Value)
Next iRow
Next
```

As you can see in the image below, Rental Amount and Deposit Amount have worked, though Deposit Amount has also happend in the column AL, which should have Rent Frequency. Similarly Column AT should have "PROPERTY TYPE" and AV should have "FURNISHED TYPE" and so on and so forth...

[image]

Comment: If you're inserting columns like that, you want to start with the rightmost column and work left.

Comment: @BigBen I'm not going to ask you to write it for me, but what would that initially look like? We've got "for all columns, insert a column to the left", and then we have "set every second column = trim(cell on left)". How would I make a start turning that bacckwards

Comment: Building on @BigBen comments above, notice that `maxColumns` is calculated before all the inserting starts. Then, when the loop starts inserting columns, what you thought was the "last max column" number has actually been pushed to the right. So when the loop reaches that max column number, it's "working backwards" because so many columns have been inserted already.

Comment: `For colx = maxColumns to 2 Step -1`. Then change the `colx - 1` to just `colx`.

Comment: @PeterT Wouldn't that be correct though? It's counting all current Columns, and doubling the number, because inserting is effectively doubling the number?

Comment: It's not "doubling the number". `maxColumns` stays the same even as new columns are inserted. That's why you need to work from right to left. If your max column is initially 8 for example, and you start inserting columns, eventually column 8 will be one of those columns you inserted, or an existing column that has been moved right, not the original column 8, which has shifted right and is no longer the 8th column.

Comment: @AAA pretty much exactly that yeah, so we get with something like columns A-B-C then ending up as OrangeA-TrimmedA-OrangeB-Trim...so on and so on

Comment: @AAA It's so we can keep a blatantly obvious flow of what's been/being edited as you read along. Column AT might end up having 4 more columns manually made just to show working etc.

Comment: @BigBen I've tried a few different versions of your line, but nothing worked. It didn't even copy anything out for a few attempts, which is likely more on me tbh.

Comment: @C.Fsh, try the answer below and remember to [upvote and mark as accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your entire code with this:

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub Macro1()
Dim LCol As Long, LRow As Long, i as Long, j as Long
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1", .Cells(LRow, LCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
    For i = 1 To (LCol*2 - 1) Step 2
        .Columns(i+1).Insert
        For j = 1 To LastRow
            .Cells(j, i+1).Value = Trim(.Cells(j, i).Value)
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That `Trim` line will throw a Type Mismatch error. You can't `Trim` an array like that. You're missing a parentheses on the left side too.

Comment: @AAA syntax error on
LRow = .Cells(1, .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: `.Rows.Count, 1` - it's rows first, columns second.

Comment: You're missing a `Next`.

Comment: @BigBen, already fixed it. Thanks a lot. My mind was elsewhere.

Comment: @AAA not at all, I'm afraid to say that it didn't even run at first. I have Option Explicit so the lines containing "j" flagged errors, and when I tried to make it work, it just made everything orange, inserted orange columns and didn't copy anything across. My bad for not mentioning Option Explicit, but no idea what I would do to fix the rest of it

Comment: @AAA That almost worked enough, I've managed to tweak it to exactly what I needed, so thanks :)

Comment: @C.Fsh what tweak did you have to make, so I can update it?